# how to set customize onclick to an element in React class component

Tags: reactjs

hi i want set customize onClick function for an element in React class component like this :

```
class Customers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);
    this.button = document.getElementById("GanttExport_delete"); // here is the element that i want to set onclick function  
  }
}
button.onclick = function { //do somthing }
```

I want to customize the onClick function for this button.

Comment: This is simply not the way React code is written. `getElementById` is mostly avoided. If its indispensable, ref should be used. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i used some package that i don't have access to the button i want to get, and customize the onClick function ( the packages name is syncfusion )

Comment: Is this button inside or outside the `Customers` component ? Is it inside any component at all ?

Comment: its inside of Customers

Comment: So you are rendering this button inside `Customers` ?

Comment: this Button is inside the package that i have use in customers, and i don't access to it  but i have it's id

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, this button already exists outside React scope & needs to be controlled from `Customers` component.

Refs cannot be used as the button exists outside `Customers` scope.

The DOM can be accessed after the component has mounted.

```
class Customers extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super(arguments);
        this.button = document.getElementById("GanttExport_delete");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.button.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick );
    }

    handleButtonClick=(evt)= {

    }


}
```